# Loading user control one by one in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple user controls in a single .aspx page I want to load the User Controls one by one using c#. Is this possible to load the user controls like Lazy Loading.(One control should load first than other will start loading and so on..)

Comment: Which part of code you want @ManojPilania My question is simple I want to load a UC - A after A get Loaded I want to load B and so on...(I am using asp .Net 3.0)

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290592/dynamically-load-a-user-control-ascx-in-a-asp-net-website/1290685#1290685

Comment: This is how the Load-event of user controls are normally triggered...

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate controls like it's described on this MSDN page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.ASPX
You can use Page.Controls.Add method. But I'm not sure about what you want to achieve exactly. Because you can't "skip" page/controls lifecycle. It means that you can add all controls sequentially inside PreInit event, for example, but the each control will have it's own Load, Render and other control events.

Comment: Thanks @Perevalov for the answer, the reason why I want to load it sequentially is each control is having huge data that is effecting performance of the page. So I want the UC to load one after another.

Comment: But it will not give you any performance benefits. Since everything is processed on a server, client will not see anything in the browser until all your controls will be processed.

Comment: If you want to improve performance of your page and you can't optimize each control, then try to split your page to few smaller. Each page will contains just few your heavy controls. Try to have a look at Tabs components from AjaxControlToolkit http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/tabs/tabs.aspx and its OnDemand feature. It will be not perfect, but fastest way to implement it in WebForms.

Comment: I can't put the controls in Tab @perevalov the scenario is I am having  graphs in each usercontrol and the page is dashboard page for me onclick of submit button it'll load the graphs which are in user controls so, I want to load one UC than the other so that the page will render fast.

Answer (score 0):

user controls can be loaded dynamically using  [LoadControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) 
All the controls on the page have to go through ASP.NET page-life cycle flow. what do you mean by lazy loading?

Comment: Lazy Loading means I want to load the controls one after the other while scrolling.

Comment: Sure. In that case it can be done through AJAX by detecting browser events. [Render the usercontrol as HTML string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk91d11a.aspx) and return in AJAX response to display on UI. But I doubt if if you really want to do this.